# benchmark() like MySQL functions which can be potential to use in SQL injections?

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

We are getting sql injections continuously and causing heavy load on servers.the sql injection statements using  benchmark() functions.
benchmark() like MySQL functions which can be potential to use in SQL injections?

Comment: So fix the code to *prevent* SQL Injection .. whatever `benchmark()` is (it's not a standard function), if it allows SQL Injection (or even DDoS), get rid of it ..

Comment: from DB side can we do any thing to block this type of functions?

Comment: Not really. Sure, you can use limit permissions to tables or impose account limits, etc - but the fundamental problem is broken code that has a blatant attack vector.

Comment: this is the business time so we can't able to do code changes.so we are searching for other solutions..

Comment: Any "solution" except fixing the problem is a poor solution - "business time" is not an excuse. The problem may also be mitigated at the application interface (e.g. PHP) by requiring registration or other means. There are likely 3rd party sanitation/etc proxies, but see above.

Answer (score 0):

Time consuming functions like [`BENCHMARK`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_benchmark) and [`SLEEP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep) are used to exploit SQL injections, where the result of the injection is not directly visible to the attacker, thus called *blind SQL injections*.

In a manner similar to the boolean-based technique, the time consuming functions `BENCHMARK`/`SLEEP` are injected and affect the server’s response depending on a specified condition:

```
… IF(EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mysql.users WHERE username='root' AND SUBSTR(password, 3, 1)='x'), SLEEP(5), 1) …
```

This injected `IF` would call `SLEEP(5)` if the third character of the root’s password is `x` and thus extend the server’s response time by five seconds.

So if the response time takes five seconds longer that the average response time, an attacker can conclude that there is an `x` at the third position of the root’s password. By this an attacker can reconstruct the root’s password character by character.